# If $P,Q,R$ are natural numbers where $P$ and $Q$ are primes, and $Q$ divides $PR$, which of the following is true?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

If $P,Q,R$ are natural numbers where $P$ and $Q$ are primes, and $Q$ divides $PR$, which of the following is true?

1. $P\mid\,Q$
2. $P\mid\,R$
3. $P\mid\,QR$
4. $P\mid\,PQ$

I know that the last option is correct, but how? Thank you in advance.
***Edit***: The third option is $P|QR$ 
Original: The third option was $P|PR$.

Comment: Please explain in simple terms as I am just a high school student.

Comment: If it is the number "PQ" being specified, please explain, if they are just products it is very simple.

Comment: It is a simple consequence of the definition of divisibilty. $$a|b \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} / b = ka$$
In that case 3 is also true.

Comment: @Sriram D ; the last two statements always are true. For the first case consider the counter-example: $P=2, Q=3, R=6$, and for the second statement consider the counter-exampe $P=2, Q=3, R=9$.

Comment: Thank you guys, you made it clear that it is a product of the terms, as I mentioned in the second comment, it was not necessary to explain it as it was the product, I thought that "PR" meant 10*P+R.

Comment: Really sorry as the third option was QR.

Comment: @Sriram D ; For the first three statements only consider the following counter example: 
$$P=2, Q=3, R=9.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what the numbers $p$ and $q$ are, $p$ will always divide $pq$ because, by definition:

> $x|y$ if and only if there exists some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $y=kx$.

In your case, $pq = q\cdot p$, which means that $p|q$ (because you can take $x=p, y=pq$ and $k=q$ in the definition.

For the same reason $p|pr$, so the third property is also true.

---

The other two properties can be either true or false:

1. Property $1$ can be true (for example, if $p=2,q=2$) or false (if $p=2,q=3$ for example)
2. Property $2$ can be true (for example, $p=2, q=2, r=2$) or false ($p=2, q=2, r=3$).

Answer (score 1):

The last statement is always true.

For the first three statements only, consider the following counter example: 
$$P=2, Q=3, R=9.$$